# Prestashop change url backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I am looking for information about how I should be proceed to change the url access to prestashop backoffice. actually we have access to the backoffice using this url www.xxx.com/backoffice/index.php

We need to know the steps to change the backoffice (name) to x exemple www.xxx.com/myownname/index.php

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the "backoffice" folder to "myownname". That's all.